# 2D harmonic oscillator: polar versus Cartesian eigenstates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra

Consider the usual two-dimensional harmonic oscillator (2D HO) with the Hamiltonian $$
H =
-\frac{1}{2}\nabla_x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2
-\frac{1}{2}\nabla_y^2 + \frac{1}{2}y^2.
$$
In Cartesian coordinates, the solution is a family of states
$$
|n_x\rangle |n_y\rangle,
$$
where the labels $n_x$ and $n_y$ correspond to the number of excitations of the one-dimensional HOs. On the other hand, solving in polar coordinates, one obtains instead a family of states
$$
|n,m\rangle,
$$
where now these states are also eigenstates of the angular momentum operator with the eigenvalue $m$.

How to switch between the two families of solutions? In other words, what is the decomposition
$$
|n,m\rangle
=
\sum_{n_x,n_y}
c_{n,m,n_x,n_y}
|n_x\rangle |n_y\rangle?
$$

I know that for example
$$
c_{0,0,0,0}=1
$$
and
$$
c_{0,1,1,0}=1/\sqrt{2},
\quad
c_{0,1,0,1}=1/\sqrt{2},
$$
but is there perhaps a table somewhere, or a systematic procedure to obtain this decomposition for arbitrary states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to investigate the operators
$$
\hat a^\dagger_\pm=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(a^\dagger_x\pm ia^\dagger_y\right)\, ,\qquad \hat a_\pm=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(a_x\mp ia_y\right)\, ,
$$
and in particular $[\hat L_z,\hat a^\dagger_\pm]$.  It should then be an easy matter to construct the $\vert n,m\rangle$ basis in the form
$$
\left(a_-^\dagger\right)^\alpha\left(a_+^\dagger\right)^\beta\vert 0\rangle
$$
and compute its overlap with the $\vert n_xn_y\rangle$ basis.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I will post the full expression as an answer below, as comments do not seem to accommodate such things.

Answer (score 0):

The answer which can be derived using the rotation operators provided by ZeroTheHero's answer is
\begin{align}
|n,m\rangle = &
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!(n+|m|)!}}\frac{1}{2^{\left(2n+|m|\right)/2}}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n+|m|}\binom{n}{j}\binom{n+|m|}{k}
\\
&\times i^{\mathrm{sng}(m)\cdot(k-j)}\sqrt{\left(2n+|m|-j-k\right)!\left(j+k\right)!}
\,\,
|2n+|m|-j-k\rangle_{x}|j+k\rangle_{y},
\end{align}
which works for any $m$ (both positive and negative), and where I use standard notation for [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), while the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) is nonstandard. In particular, it is $1$ for zero or positive $m$, and $-1$ for negative $m$.

Comment: glad you like it.  It's a "old" trick - which shows my age!  I'm pretty sure you can find a discussion of this in the Quantum book of Cohen-Tannoudji et al.

Comment: I actually knew this, but could not connect the dots somehow - perhaps this means I am not that young either any more. Your answer put me back on the right track and saved a lot of time, thanks a lot for that :)